# how can i link my station_id to the id of the second table so i have in the end 3 rows?

Tags: sql

[Databank rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxgxR.jpg)

I dont know how to link my station_id(weatherinformation) to the weatherstation.id. Help would be appreciated :).

Comment: It doesn't look like the station_id column is filled in anywhere? And you probably want to use an INNER JOIN instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.